# Join in Pig and creating a new column

Tags: apache-pig

I have two data sets

```
Definition of schema A - Name, city, state
A= {
  Ram,    Sunnyvale,  CA
  Soju,   Austin,     TX
  Rathos, Bangalore,  Karnataka
  Mike,   Portland,   OR
}

B = {
    Ram,  Refund
    Soju, Refund
}
```

I would like to join these two  tables based on state and have the output as follows

```
Schema Definition - Name,City,State,RefundIssued (Yes/No)
  Ram,Sunnyvale,CA,yes
  Soju,Austin,TX,yes
  Rathos,Bangalore,Karnataka,no
  Mike,Portland, OR,no
```

I am not sure on how to specify that I need extra column and which goes on the logic

```
A = load 'data1.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (name: chararray,city: chararray,state: chararray);
B= load 'data2.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (name: chararray,type: chararray);
C = join A by name LEFT OUTER,B by name;  
D = foreach C generate A::name as firstname,B::type as charge_type;
--how to add new column which goes on refund issued as yes /no
store D into '1outdata.txt';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
A = load 'data1.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (name: chararray,city: chararray,state: chararray);
B= load 'data2.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (name: chararray,type: chararray);
C = join A by name LEFT OUTER,B by name;  
D = foreach C generate A::name as name , A::city as city, A::state as state, (B::type == 'Refund' ? 'True' : 'False') as RefundIssued
```

Note that RefundIssues can be 'true', 'false' or null because of how bincond works. If you want null (left join finds no match or field value is null) to be translated into false then use:

```
E = foreach D generate name , city, state, (RefundIssued IS NULL ? 'False' : RefundIssued) as RefundIssued
```